# How to plot average hourly values over time

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to plot the average hourly temperature over the month of December. I have a temperature point logged for every hour over the course of the month and would like to plot the average temperature at each hour within a 24hr period to see what a typical day looks like (i.e. average at timepoint 01:00:00, average at timepoint 02:00:00, etc.). Below is a subset of the dataframe. I think I'm having trouble formatting date and time correctly.

```
structure(list(
  Date = structure(c(17866, 17866, 17866, 17866, 
                     17866, 17866, 17866, 17866, 17866, 17866, 17866, 17866, 17866, 
                     17866, 17866, 17866, 17866, 17866, 17866, 17866, 17866, 17866, 
                     17866, 17866, 17867, 17867, 17867, 17867, 17867, 17867, 17867, 
                     17867, 17867, 17867, 17867, 17867, 17867, 17867, 17867, 17867, 
                     17867, 17867, 17867, 17867, 17867, 17867, 17867, 17867, 17868, 
                     17868, 17868, 17868, 17868, 17868, 17868, 17868, 17868, 17868, 
                     17868, 17868, 17868, 17868, 17868, 17868, 17868, 17868, 17868, 
                     17868, 17868, 17868, 17868, 17868), class = "Date"), 
  Time = structure(c(0, 
                     3600, 7200, 10800, 14400, 18000, 21600, 25200, 28800, 32400, 
                     36000, 39600, 43200, 46800, 50400, 54000, 57600, 61200, 64800, 
                     68400, 72000, 75600, 79200, 82800, 0, 3600, 7200, 10800, 14400, 
                     18000, 21600, 25200, 28800, 32400, 36000, 39600, 43200, 46800, 
                     50400, 54000, 57600, 61200, 64800, 68400, 72000, 75600, 79200, 
                     82800, 0, 3600, 7200, 10800, 14400, 18000, 21600, 25200, 28800, 
                     32400, 36000, 39600, 43200, 46800, 50400, 54000, 57600, 61200, 
                     64800, 68400, 72000, 75600, 79200, 82800), 
                   class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), 
  Tmp = c(25.1, 25.2, 24.9, 24.2, 24.4, 24.6, 
          24.4, 23.8, 24.4, 25.1, 25.2, 25.3, 25.6, 25.7, 25.7, 25.9, 26, 
          25.7, 25.7, 25.5, 25.6, 25.5, 25.6, 25.3, 25.2, 25.2, 25, 24.3, 
          24.6, 24.5, 24.5, 24, 24.7, 25.1, 25.2, 25.4, 25.6, 25.8, 25.8, 
          25.9, 26, 25.8, 25.8, 25.6, 25.6, 25.6, 25.6, 25.4, 25.2, 25.2, 
          25, 24.6, 24.6, 24.5, 24.5, 24.1, 24.8, 25.2, 25.1, 25.4, 25.5, 
          25.8, 25.7, 26, 26, 25.8, 25.7, 25.6, 25.6, 25.6, 25.5, 25.3), 
  pHx2 = c(8.19, 8.18, 8.17, 8.15, 8.13, 8.12, 8.11, 8.1, 8.11, 
           8.15, 8.17, 8.19, 8.21, 8.23, 8.25, 8.27, 8.3, 8.31, 8.32, 
           8.31, 8.29, 8.26, 8.24, 8.23, 8.21, 8.2, 8.18, 8.17, 8.16, 
           8.15, 8.13, 8.12, 8.12, 8.16, 8.18, 8.19, 8.21, 8.23, 8.25, 
           8.27, 8.3, 8.31, 8.32, 8.31, 8.27, 8.25, 8.24, 8.22, 8.21, 
           8.19, 8.18, 8.16, 8.15, 8.14, 8.13, 8.12, 8.13, 8.19, 8.21, 
           8.23, 8.24, 8.26, 8.29, 8.3, 8.32, 8.33, 8.34, 8.33, 8.31, 
           8.28, 8.26, 8.24), 
  Tmpx2 = c(25.1, 25.2, 25, 24.2, 24.3, 
            24.6, 24.3, 23.7, 24.5, 25.1, 25.1, 25.4, 25.6, 25.8, 25.7, 
            26, 25.9, 25.8, 25.8, 25.6, 25.5, 25.6, 25.5, 25.4, 25.1, 
            25.1, 25, 24.3, 24.6, 24.5, 24.5, 24, 24.8, 25.2, 25.2, 25.4, 
            25.6, 25.8, 25.8, 26, 26, 25.7, 25.8, 25.6, 25.6, 25.6, 25.6, 
            25.3, 25.2, 25.2, 24.9, 24.6, 24.5, 24.5, 24.5, 24, 24.9, 
            25.1, 25.2, 25.4, 25.6, 25.7, 25.7, 26, 26, 25.8, 25.7, 25.6, 
            25.5, 25.5, 25.6, 25.5), 
  pHx3 = c("8.18", "8.16", "8.15", 
           "8.13", "8.12", "8.1", "8.09", "8.09", "8.13", "8.18", "8.21", 
           "8.25", "8.28", "8.32", "8.34", "8.37", "8.39", "8.4", "8.38", 
           "8.35", "8.32", "8.3", "8.27", "8.25", "8.23", "8.2", "8.18", 
           "8.17", "8.15", "8.14", "8.13", "8.12", "8.16", "8.2", "8.24", 
           "8.27", "8.3", "8.33", "8.35", "8.39", "8.41", "8.43", "8.41", 
           "8.38", "8.35", "8.33", "8.29", "8.27", "8.25", "8.23", "8.2", 
           "8.19", "8.17", "8.15", "8.14", "8.13", "8.18", "8.24", "8.28", 
           "8.3", "8.33", "8.36", "8.39", "8.42", "8.44", "8.45", "8.43", 
           "8.4", "8.36", "8.33", "8.3", "8.28"), 
  dttm = structure(c(1543622400, 
                     1543626000, 1543629600, 1543633200, 1543636800, 1543640400, 
                     1543644000, 1543647600, 1543651200, 1543654800, 1543658400, 
                     1543662000, 1543665600, 1543669200, 1543672800, 1543676400, 
                     1543680000, 1543683600, 1543687200, 1543690800, 1543694400, 
                     1543698000, 1543701600, 1543705200, 1543708800, 1543712400, 
                     1543716000, 1543719600, 1543723200, 1543726800, 1543730400, 
                     1543734000, 1543737600, 1543741200, 1543744800, 1543748400, 
                     1543752000, 1543755600, 1543759200, 1543762800, 1543766400, 
                     1543770000, 1543773600, 1543777200, 1543780800, 1543784400, 
                     1543788000, 1543791600, 1543795200, 1543798800, 1543802400, 
                     1543806000, 1543809600, 1543813200, 1543816800, 1543820400, 
                     1543824000, 1543827600, 1543831200, 1543834800, 1543838400, 
                     1543842000, 1543845600, 1543849200, 1543852800, 1543856400, 
                     1543860000, 1543863600, 1543867200, 1543870800, 1543874400, 
                     1543878000), 
                   class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), 
  .Names = c("Date", "Time", "Tmp", "pHx2", "Tmpx2", "pHx3", "dttm"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -72L), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Would you care if I were to change the initial class structure of the time series>?

Comment: No, go ahead and change the structure if you think that will help downstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the class of the time object:

`...class = ("Time"), units = "secs"),`

I was able to aggregate based on the 24 hour time.

```
  #Asumming we call our structure "df"

  #Divide Time series by 3600 to get hour
  df$Time<-df$Time/3600

  #Aggregate by mean based on hour of day
  test<-aggregate(df$Tmp, by=df["Time"], FUN=mean)

  #RE-name for clarity
  names(test)<-c("Time(24 Hr)", "Temp (degree C)")

>Test

   Time(24 Hr) Temp (degree C)
1            0        25.16667
2            1        25.20000
3            2        24.96667
4            3        24.36667
5            4        24.53333
6            5        24.53333
7            6        24.46667
8            7        23.96667
9            8        24.63333
10           9        25.13333
11          10        25.16667
12          11        25.36667
13          12        25.56667
14          13        25.76667
15          14        25.73333
16          15        25.93333
17          16        26.00000
18          17        25.76667
19          18        25.73333
20          19        25.56667
21          20        25.60000
22          21        25.56667
23          22        25.56667
24          23        25.33333
```

Comment: Great, thank you for the help! That definitely gets me going in the right direction.